# Elasticsearch aggregation on parent properties

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a parent/child relation and an searching on the children.

Is it possible to create an aggregation on the parent properties ?

e.g. parent is a POST and children are COMMENTs. If the parent has a property "category", would it be possible to search for COMMENTs and have an aggregation on the categories of the parent POSTs ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? If you do a has_child query, then you will get back parents, which you should be able to aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easy and I feel your question refers to something else:

```
GET /my_index/post/_search    # query the POSTs type
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "comment",      # this is the COMMENT
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "data": "whatever"  # query the content of the COMMENT
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "categories_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category"   # aggregate on the category of the POST (since the POST is the type we query in the URL)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I've written, I am searching for comments.

Comment: Ok. And the `has_child` query above does allow querying for comments.

Comment: but you are searching for posts /my_index/post/_search. I would expert /my_index/comment/_search

Comment: Got it now. This is not supported: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/children-agg.html. Quote from that link: _A parent aggregation (the equivalent of reverse_nested) is not supported._

Comment: you could include the `inner_hits` to show the comments with the results if you want.